# Can we find prime numbers with any sum of digits (except those divisible by three)

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I guess that this question is not something new and that there must be people who wanted to know if this question has an affirmative answer, but I would like to share it with you, because I really do not know if this is known or not?

Let us define *sum of digits* (in base 10) function $sd_{10}$ over the set of natural numbers in an obvious way as $sd_{10}(n)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_i$, where we have that $n=\sum_{i=0}^m a_i \cdot 10^i$.

If we choose some number, for example $7$ ,then we can find prime number which has its sum of digits equal to $7$, for example $61$.

If we choose some number divisible by $3$ as the sum of digits then we cannot find a prime number that has that sum of digits because it is known *that the number is divisible by $3$ if and only if sum of its digits is divisible by $3$*.

Let us also suppose here, because of the easier phrasing of the question, that the number $1$ is also prime so that if we choose that the sum of digits is $1$ we have a solution which equals $1$.

Now I would like to share this question with you:

> Is it true that for every $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{3k : k \in \mathbb N\}$ there exists at least one prime number $p$ which is such that we have $sd_{10}(p)=n$?

Comment: The approximately $10^n/n \ln 10$ primes below $10^n$ all have $sd_{10}\le 9n$, so there should be plenty of opportunities to "hit" any allowed value ...

Comment: I couldn't even consider it a heuristic..

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Is there any conjectured approximate value for questions like these?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti $1$, because I stated in the question that we take $1$ as prime because of the easier phrasing of the question.

Comment: This seems like the kind of question that is incredibly hard to answer one way or the other, unless a small counterexample is found by direct search...

Comment: @user7530 I thought that maybe it would follow from some major results about prime numbers that occured in the last, let us say, 30 years or so?

Comment: I think it is not hard to make Hagen von Eitzen heuristic approach actually work. If a moderately large value of the digit sum weren't hit, there would be large arithmetic progressions without primes, and we know quite a lot about the pseudo-random distribution of primes in APs.

Comment: Probably, a proof of this conjecture is currently out of reach. But I am very convinced that the conjecture IS true. The title is slightly incorrect because we have to rule out $1$ as well.

Comment: @Peter See that i put this sentence inside the question: "Let us also suppose here, because of the easier phrasing of the question, that the number 1 is also prime so that if we choose that the sum of digits is 1 we have a solution which equals 1."

Comment: A counterexample will hardly be detected because you would have to show that every number with digit-sum $n$ is composite. This will probably be infeasible (unless $n$ is divisible by $3$).

Comment: @Farewell: Most mathematicians would prefer to specify $n > 1$, rather than arbitrarily declare $1$ to be prime. It's sort of like saying "for the purposes of this question, let us consider $1$ to be even". (But it's not quite that bad, because in the dim and distant past there _were_ mathematicians who counted $1$ as prime.)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, for sufficiently large $n$.  This was recently proved in

Drmota, Mauduit and Rivat, "Primes with an average sum of digits".  *Compositio Mathematica*, Volume 145:2 (March 2009), pp. 271–292.

Preprint available here: http://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/drmota/DMRcomp2.pdf

Theorem 1.1 is a type of Central Limit Theorem for the sum-of-digits function on primes, showing that when the number of digits is large, then the digit sum tends to be clustered normally around the average.  Their result is strong enough to show that if you want to have a digit sum of exactly $n$ in base $10$ then you can achieve this with a $\lceil 2n/9 \rceil$-digit prime, provided $n$ is large enough.

I am not familiar enough with the paper to know how effective the convergence is and whether your question can be given a full affirmation after a practical amount of computation.

Answer (score 1):

Ruling out $n=1$ and $3|n$ we have the following conjecture :

> For every natural number $n$, there is a prime with digitsum $n$.

The conjecture is definitely true for $2\le n\le 200$ (I found proven primes with PARI/GP) and very probably true for $2\le n\le 1000$ (The numbers I found passed $10$ strong probable-prime-tests)

Since there are infinite many numbers with digit-sum $n$ for every $n$, and many of these numbers are "small", it is very likely that we find a prime for every $n$.

This should give an overhelming heuristical argument to believe that the claim is true for all $n$.

A proof of this conjecture is very probably currently out of reach.

Comment: You wrote "Perhaps someone can calculate the number of integers with digitsum n for a given n.". There is an infinite number of integers with digit sum $n$ for every $n$.

Comment: Oops, you are right. This makes the probability that the claim is true even much higher.

Comment: Yes indeed. :) :)

Comment: Now you wrote "Since there are infinite many numbers with digit-sum n for every n, and many of these numbers are "small", it is very likely that we find a prime for every n." But many of these numbers are, on the contrary, big, because you can choose some number that has the sum of the first $k$ digits equal to $n-1$, then after that $k$ digits you can add as many zeros as you want, and then choose the last digit $1$ to obtain a sum $n$, right?

Comment: But there are also many "small" such numbers, numbers with, lets say, $\frac{n}{2}$ digits. I did not mean : Most of the numbers are "small".

Comment: Do you think that harder question would be true, this one: That for every $n \in \mathbb N \setminus \{3k:k \in \mathbb N\} \bigcup \{1\}$ there exist infinitely many prime numbers with digit sum $n$?

Comment: Probably yes, inserting zeros at the right place should always produce a prime, no matter which number coprime to $30$ is given initially.

Comment: @Farewell It is likely that we only need the digits $0$ and $1$ to find a prime.

Comment: I was thinking along the same lines. Maybe we could also do it with $1$ and $3$ only.

Comment: If you want to continue the discussion, we should remove unnecessary posts and enter a chat room

Comment: Nope, thank you. I am not in a mood for discussions. Nice of you to invite me.

Comment: Actually, Mauduit and Rivat have been working on digit sums of primes for some time, and the existence question is now well within reach.  I give a reference in my answer.  I don't believe this method is strong enough to obtain infinitely many primes, though.