# The proportion of primes whose digit sum is prime, out of all primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, arithmetic

### ***Background:***

*I recently got an idea. My idea was analyzing primes whose digit sum is prime.*

This is a property of some primes ($> 1$ digit):

**The sum of its digits is prime.**

I will call a special prime like this $P$.

For primes in the range $1<p<100$, these are all $P$:

$$2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23, 29, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89$$

Here the proportion of $P$s out of all primes in $1<p<100$ is $\frac{14}{25} = 0.56$ (more than half).

For this general proportion, the number of $P$ divided by the total primes in some range $1<p<a$, I will define a function $\text{prop}(a)$ for that proportion. $\text{prop}(100)=\frac{14}{25}=0.56$.

To find the $P$s and the number of $P$s in a range $1<p<n$, I made the computer automate it (I’m gonna trust the python program, if anyone finds mistakes then please let me know)

Hence, in the range $1<p<1000$, these are the $P$:

$$2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23, 29, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 101, 113, 131, 137, 139, 151, 157, 173, 179, 191, 193, 197, 199, 223, 227, 229, 241, 263, 269, 281, 283, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 353, 359, 373, 379, 397, 401, 409, 421, 443, 449, 461, 463, 467, 487, 557, 571, 577, 593, 599, 601, 607, 641, 643, 647, 661, 683, 719, 733, 739, 751, 757, 773, 797, 809, 821, 823, 827, 829, 863, 881, 883, 887, 911, 919, 937, 953, 971, 977, 991$$

and $\text{prop}(1000)\approx \frac{89}{168} \approx 0.52$.

And I’ll give it to you also for $1<p<10000$ (sorry for the spam of numbers):

$$\tiny{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 23, 29, 41, 43, 47, 61, 67, 83, 89, 101, 113, 131, 137, 139, 151, 157, 173, 179, 191, 193, 197, 199, 223, 227, 229, 241, 263, 269, 281, 283, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 353, 359, 373, 379, 397, 401, 409, 421, 443, 449, 461, 463, 467, 487, 557, 571, 577, 593, 599, 601, 607, 641, 643, 647, 661, 683, 719, 733, 739, 751, 757, 773, 797, 809, 821, 823, 827, 829, 863, 881, 883, 887, 911, 919, 937, 953, 971, 977, 991, 1013, 1019, 1031, 1033, 1039, 1051, 1091, 1093, 1097, 1103, 1109, 1123, 1129, 1163, 1181, 1187, 1213, 1217, 1231, 1237, 1259, 1277, 1279, 1291, 1297, 1301, 1303, 1307, 1321, 1327, 1361, 1367, 1381, 1433, 1439, 1451, 1453, 1459, 1471, 1493, 1499, 1523, 1543, 1549, 1567, 1583, 1613, 1619, 1637, 1657, 1693, 1697, 1709, 1721, 1723, 1741, 1747, 1783, 1787, 1811, 1831, 1871, 1873, 1877, 1901, 1907, 1949, 2003, 2027, 2029, 2063, 2069, 2081, 2083, 2087, 2089, 2111, 2113, 2131, 2137, 2153, 2179, 2203, 2207, 2221, 2243, 2267, 2269, 2281, 2287, 2311, 2333, 2339, 2351, 2357, 2371, 2377, 2393, 2399, 2423, 2441, 2447, 2467, 2531, 2539, 2551, 2557, 2579, 2591, 2593, 2609, 2621, 2647, 2663, 2683, 2687, 2711, 2713, 2719, 2731, 2753, 2777, 2791, 2801, 2803, 2843, 2861, 2917, 2939, 2953, 2957, 2971, 2999, 3011, 3019, 3037, 3079, 3109, 3121, 3163, 3167, 3169, 3181, 3187, 3217, 3251, 3253, 3257, 3259, 3271, 3299, 3301, 3307, 3323, 3329, 3343, 3347, 3361, 3389, 3413, 3433, 3457, 3491, 3527, 3529, 3541, 3547, 3581, 3583, 3613, 3617, 3631, 3637, 3659, 3671, 3673, 3677, 3691, 3701, 3709, 3727, 3761, 3767, 3833, 3851, 3853, 3907, 3923, 3929, 3943, 3947, 3989, 4001, 4003, 4007, 4021, 4027, 4049, 4111, 4133, 4139, 4153, 4157, 4159, 4177, 4201, 4229, 4241, 4243, 4261, 4283, 4289, 4337, 4339, 4357, 4373, 4391, 4397, 4409, 4421, 4423, 4441, 4447, 4463, 4481, 4483, 4513, 4517, 4519, 4591, 4603, 4621, 4643, 4649, 4663, 4733, 4751, 4793, 4799, 4801, 4861, 4889, 4919, 4931, 4933, 4937, 4951, 4973, 4999, 5011, 5039, 5051, 5059, 5077, 5099, 5101, 5107, 5147, 5167, 5189, 5231, 5233, 5237, 5273, 5279, 5297, 5303, 5309, 5323, 5347, 5381, 5387, 5413, 5417, 5419, 5431, 5437, 5471, 5477, 5501, 5503, 5507, 5521, 5527, 5563, 5581, 5639, 5651, 5653, 5657, 5693, 5701, 5741, 5743, 5783, 5813, 5851, 5879, 5897, 5903, 5923, 5927, 5981, 5987, 6007, 6029, 6043, 6047, 6067, 6089, 6113, 6131, 6133, 6151, 6173, 6197, 6203, 6221, 6229, 6247, 6263, 6269, 6287, 6311, 6317, 6337, 6353, 6359, 6373, 6421, 6427, 6449, 6481, 6551, 6553, 6571, 6599, 6607, 6661, 6689, 6719, 6733, 6737, 6779, 6791, 6803, 6823, 6827, 6841, 6863, 6869, 6911, 6917, 6959, 6971, 6977, 6997, 7013, 7019, 7039, 7057, 7079, 7103, 7109, 7121, 7127, 7129, 7187, 7211, 7213, 7219, 7237, 7253, 7307, 7309, 7321, 7349, 7411, 7417, 7433, 7451, 7457, 7499, 7507, 7523, 7529, 7541, 7547, 7561, 7583, 7589, 7673, 7691, 7699, 7703, 7723, 7727, 7741, 7789, 7817, 7853, 7877, 7879, 7901, 7907, 7949, 8009, 8069, 8081, 8087, 8111, 8117, 8171, 8191, 8209, 8221, 8243, 8263, 8311, 8317, 8353, 8423, 8429, 8443, 8447, 8461, 8513, 8537, 8573, 8597, 8599, 8609, 8623, 8627, 8641, 8663, 8669, 8681, 8689, 8713, 8731, 8753, 8779, 8803, 8807, 8821, 8849, 8861, 8867, 8887, 8933, 8951, 9011, 9013, 9059, 9091, 9103, 9109, 9127, 9161, 9181, 9239, 9257, 9293, 9323, 9341, 9343, 9413, 9419, 9431, 9433, 9437, 9473, 9479, 9491, 9497, 9521, 9587, 9613, 9631, 9677, 9679, 9697, 9721, 9743, 9749, 9767, 9769, 9787, 9811, 9833, 9839, 9851, 9857, 9859, 9901, 9923, 9929, 9941, 9949, 9967}$$

Here, $\text{prop}(10000) \approx \frac{590}{1229} \approx 0.48$.

Here are some other proportions I found using Python:

- $\text{prop}(100 \ 000) \approx \frac{3883}{9592} \approx 0.40$
- $\text{prop}(1 \ 000 \ 000)\approx \frac{30123}{78498} \approx 0.38 $
- $\text{prop}(10 \ 000 \ 000)\approx \frac{246982}{664579} \approx  0.37$
- $\text{prop}(100 \ 000 \ 000) \approx \frac{2163899}{5761455} \approx 0.37$
- $\text{prop}(1 \ 000 \ 000 \ 000) \approx \frac{18661619}{50847534}\approx 0.37$

### ***Question:***

**What does this proportion, $\text{prop}(a)$, approach in the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \text{prop}(10^n)$? For me there are two options:**

- **It randomly jumps.**
- **It approaches a value $0.36 > v > 0.37$**.
- **It approaches $0$.**

I’m not sure which one.

Note: This entire idea and algorithm was just an idea of mine.

Comment: What does your notation $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} 1<p<10^n$ mean?

Comment: @aig basically that’s the limit as the upper bound for the primes goes to infinity, in terms of $10^n$. It’s just some freestyle notation

Comment: Maybe it’s better to denote your proportion. For example, let $f(n)$ be the number of good primes in $[11,n]$ divided by the number of all primes. Then we want to find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f(10^n)$. **Edit** Your whole post is devoted to this proportion, so it’s better to have a notation for it.

Comment: It's not clear what $\lim_{n\to \infty} 1<p<10^n$ means unless you somehow mean $\infty<p<10^n$ which I doubt.  I suggest removing that and editing for clarity.

Comment: As to the question, my prior would be that numbers which are the sums of the digits of primes behave "just like" randomly selected numbers, so the prime number theorem would apply.  I'd work out what that implied for your question and then look at the data to see if we had reason to reject that hypothesis.

Comment: @lulu I defined a function $\text{prop}(a)$ which gives the proportion of $P$ in a range of $1<p<a$. Now the limit should make sense.

Comment: I don't understand.  I suggest defining a clear process.  Select a prime $p$ at random (from the primes $<N$, say).   What is the probability that $S(p)$ is also prime?  It's a bit confusing, since, of course $S(p)$ might equal $S(q)$ for a different prime $q$, as $10=S(37)=S(73)$.  But the average process might return a sensible number.  As i say, my guess, and it is just a guess, is that on average this is just given by the prime number theorem estimate.  This might be wrong!  But it should be testable.

Comment: Should stress:  I very much doubt that anything would be provable, so it's all speculative. But it might be interesting to learn that there was some significant bias in the picture...if there is, it might be possible to say something about that.

Comment: @lulu That’s not the point. All we are doing is taking the number $n_1$ of primes $P$ (where the sum of the digits is prime) out of the number $n_2$ of all primes between $1$ and a power of $10$. Then we take the proportion as $\frac{n_1}{n_2}$.

Comment: Note:  [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765998/can-we-find-prime-numbers-with-any-sum-of-digits-except-those-divisible-by-thre) suggests that *every* natural number, outside the multiples of $3$ of course, is the sum of the digits of a prime.  Which, if true, would mean that you are just asking "given that a natural number is prime to $3$, what is the probability that it is prime?"

Comment: For primes in the interval $(1,100)$ should the proportion be $14/25$?

Comment: @ShyamalSayak yes, my bad.

Comment: I think just proving that there are infinitely many such primes already requires very advanced techniques.

Comment: Your value for $10^9$ looks very wrong.

Comment: Have you checked that number for $10^9$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP refuses to engage.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I got that value from here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4879597/is-the-number-of-additive-primes-between-1-and-1-text-000-text-000-tex… I just realized they changed it.

Answer (score 8):

This sequence of primes has been studied before, and is sequence A046704 in the [On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/). There is a 2012 research paper by Glyn Harman devoted to analysis of the growth of the sequence (including the same definition but in a general base), which is available [here](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Harman/harman2.pdf) but is very technical. (Without assuming strong unsolved conjectures you can't analyse its growth directly but have to look at how the sum of reciprocals of entries of the sequence grows.)

[edit] Looking at the paper in more detail, Harman proves that the sum of the reciprocals of such primes below $n$ is about $1.5\log\log\log n$, where $c$ is some constant that depends on the base. Since the sum of reciprocals of *all* primes up to $n$ is about $\log\log n$, it follows that provided the limit of your proportion exists, it must be $0$.

Comment: Which goes to show:  if you are looking at some sequence of integers, the *first* place you should look is the OEIS, and not Math SE. :/