# Is the number of additive primes between $1$ and $1\text{,}000 \text{,} 000 \text{,} 000$ known?

Tags: prime-numbers, reference-works

Since I’m researching and experimenting with special kinds of primes (I asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4878945/the-proportion-of-primes-whose-digit-sum-is-prime-out-of-all-primes) about them, you can see their definition there), which I just realized are called “additive primes” in mathematical terms (didn’t know), I have a question about them:

**Is the number of additive prime numbers between $1$ and $1 \text{,} 000 \text{,} 000 \text{,} 000$ known?**

I am  asking this because I am exploring the distribution of additive primes, and I am trying to find the proportion of additive primes out of all primes in a range $1<p<10^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb Z^+$. Using a Python program, I computed these values for all $0<n \leq 8$, but the program is taking too long for $n=9$ ($1 \text{,} 000 \text{,} 000 \text{,} 000$, or $1$ billion).

Hence, this ever been calculated before, maybe in a paper or somewhere? So far I can’t find anything.

Comment: You may want to try C/C++ instead of Python. That range shouldn't be a problem for low level language. Python is slow. Plus, what algorithm did you implement?

Comment: @freakish I check If a number is prime, then I check if the digit sum is prime, make a list of those for an upper bound $n$, and print the length of the list.

Comment: Python can be very slow on lists depending on exactly what you do with them.  If you just want the number don't make the list.  The digit sum cannot exceed $81$ so a list of primes up to that can speed the checking.

Comment: Right, so (1) use efficient prime test, e.g. Eratostenes sieve is very fast, although requires memory (which also can be heavily optimized by realizing that among every 6 consecutive numbers only two can be prime). (2) how do you retrieve digits from a number? If you don't do proper log arithmetic, then you must. (3) Don't make a list of results if you are only interested in its length. Just increase an int on success. Either way this becomes an optimization problem now.

Comment: Make sure to use a library like SymPy  with optimized primality checking or that does the sieve for you.

Comment: Maybe this question needs to be migrated on StackExchange, as it looks more a coding question then a mathematical one

Comment: @Marco I am really asking if this is known in the mathematical community. The code is just what I’ve been trying

Comment: I'm not sure what the point is. Even if you knew the value for $10^n$ for all $n\le10^{100}$ it wouldn't prove anything and it wouldn't change the answer, given at your earlier question, that the ratio goes to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just make a quick and dirty code that uses an already found list of primes up to 1 bilion.

The file can be found [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/billion-primes/)

The code I have used is:

```
def sum_digit(n):
    sum = 0
    while (n != 0): 
   
        sum = sum + (n % 10)
        n = n//10
   
    return sum


with open('additive_primes.txt', 'w+') as f:
    file=open("billion-primes.txt","r")

    for prime in file.readlines():
        digit_sum=sum_digit(int(prime))
        if digit_sum in (2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79):
           f.write('%s\n' %prime)

f.close()
file.close()
```

It took less then one minute to check all the primes (but I used the list of primes from the source I have linked. Of course bilion-primes.txt is the text file taken from the source

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/pghr5a3k2tmuxyzipxd92/gfg.txt.tar.gz?rlkey=ynkwi114usji39nvnqi6n5uy4&dl=0) is a link to the file containing the list of all the additive primes up to 1 bilion

If you are only interested to the number of such primes, it is:
$$
18\text{,}661\text{,}619
$$

Comment: @NotMath I have modified the number of primes. Actually the code I have posted produced a text file in which half of the rows are empty. Now  the proportion of such primes is around $0.365$ as it should be looking at the result you found for $n=8$ and the theorical asymptotic bound